# why python is giving an error saying that is a folder when it is a file?

Tags: python-2.7, biopython

I am working on a program and one of the function is to sort out a fasta file according to ID. The function is described as:

```
def sorting_files(output,my_fasta_file, sample_name):
    #to sort the fasta file that contain all the genes 
    my_file=open(my_fasta_file)
    input_handle=(my_file,'rU')
    fasta_file=SeqIO.parse(input_handle, 'fasta')
    sorted_fasta_file=(record for record in sorted(fasta_file, key=lambda x : x.id))
    sorted_file=SeqIO.write(sorted_fasta_file, output + 'sorted_' + sample_name +'.fa', 'fasta')
    return sorted_file
```

Then I am calling the function from the main as:

```
      #to sort the fasta file
   def main():    
        folders=sorted(glob.glob(opts.input_file +'/*_velvet'))         
        for folder in folders:
            my_fasta_file=glob.glob(folder +'/H*.fa')
            print my_fasta_file
            #sys.exit()
            sorted_file=sorting_files(my_fasta_file,output,sample_name)
            print 'The fasta file has been sorted, hoooray!'
    main()

When it prints my_fasta_file it prints:

['/home/path_to_file/velvet_file/sample_name_velvet/sample_name.fa']
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
File "model.py", line 82, in sorting_files
    my_file=open(my_fasta_file)
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/path_to_files/velvet_file/sample-name_velvet/'
```

I cannot figure out where the error is. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that error in your code comes with the order of your arguments.

```
def sorting_files(output,my_fasta_file, sample_name):
    ...
sorted_file=sorting_files(my_fasta_file,output,sample_name)
```

you are putting `output` where `my_fasta_file` should go and vicersa. I don't know what `output` is in your code but my guess is that it's the directory `'/home/path_to_files/velvet_file/sample-name_velvet/'`

Comment: Thanks, followed your suggestion and it is working perfectly. I'm learning python and I thought that the order was not important. Always learning.

Comment: The order is not important when you are using keyword arguments only. For the rest, the order is important.